# ES6 Promises - something like async.each?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Trying to figure-out how to find something that functional exactly like async.eachSeries, i need a list of async actions run in sequence (not in parallel) but can't find a way to do it in native ES6, can anyone advise, please?

p.s. thought about generators/yield but don't have the experience yet so I'm not realized how exactly it can help me.

**Edit 1**

per request, here is an example:

Assume this code:

```
let model1 = new MongooseModel({prop1: "a", prop2: "b"});
let model2 = new MongooseModel({prop1: "c", prop2: "d"});

let arr = [model1 , model2];
```

Now, I want to run over it in a series, not parallel, so with the "async" NPM it's easy:

```
async.eachSeries(arr, (model, next)=>{
    model.save.then(next).catch(next);
}, err=>{
    if(err) return reject(error);
    resolve();
})
```

My question is: with ES6, can I do it natively? without the NPM 'async' package?

**Edit 2**

With async/await it can be done easily:

```
let model1 = new MongooseModel({prop1: "a", prop2: "b"});
let model2 = new MongooseModel({prop1: "c", prop2: "d"});    

let arr = [model1 , model2];

for(let model of arr){
    await model.save();
}
```

Comment: You mean, the second function depends on the result of the first function?

Comment: It's not must be depend on it but must run after the previous has done.

Comment: You should give an example and state the sample input and expected output, to explain the problem properly.

Comment: Added an example, thank you!

Answer (score 50):

For those who like short answers:

```
[func1, func2].reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: The second parameter is the [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) of the reduction. E.g. this particular example is equivalent to `Promise.resolve().then(func1).then(func2)`.

Comment: Thanks, where would you put the code that will execute when *the last promise* resolves?

Comment: @SSHThis Put `.then(resultFromFunc2 => console.log("all done"))` at the end, before `;`.

Comment: Interesting, though I'm not sure how this is much different from `Promise.all([func1, func2]);`.

Comment: @ChadJohnson The async functions run in sequence, not in parallel.

Answer (score 14):

Let's say you want to call some async function on an array of data and you want them called sequentially, not in parallel.

The interface for `async.eachSeries()` is like this:

```
eachSeries(arr, iterator, [callback])
```

Here's how to simulate that with promises:

```
// define helper function that works kind of like async.eachSeries
function eachSeries(arr, iteratorFn) {
    return arr.reduce(function(p, item) {
        return p.then(function() {
            return iteratorFn(item);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

This assumes that `iteratorFn` takes the item to process as an argument and that it returns a promise.

Here's a usage example (that assumes you have a promisified `fs.readFileAsync()`) and have a function called `speak()` that returns a promise when done:

```
 var files = ["hello.dat", "goodbye.dat", "genericgreeting.dat"];
 eachSeries(files, function(file) {
     return fs.readFileAsync(file).then(function(data) {
         return speak(data);
     });
 });
```

This lets the promise infrastructure sequence everything for you.

---

It is also possible for you to sequence things manually (though I'm not sure why):

```
function eachSeries(arr, iteratorFn) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        var index = 0;

        function next() {
            if (index < arr.length) {
                try {
                    iteratorFn(arr[index++]).then(next, reject);
                } catch(e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }
        // kick off first iteration
        next();
    });
}
```

Or, a simpler version that manually chains the promises together:

```
function eachSeries(arr, iteratorFn) {
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < arr.length) {
            return iteratorFn(arr[index++]).then(next);
        }
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(next);
}
```

Note how one of the manual versions has to surround `iteratorFn()` with `try/catch` in order to make sure it is throw-safe (convert exceptions into a rejection).  `.then()` is automatically throw safe so the other schemes don't have to manually catch exceptions since `.then()` already catches them for you.

Comment: As i thought it must use recursive part to fetch the array till it's end.. in this case i assume i'll keep use aync.eachSeries..

Comment: @ShlomiSasson - there's nothing recursive in my first example so a recursive part is not necessary.  It just uses `array.reduce()` to iterate through the array and uses promises to chain together all the operations.

Comment: Yes, you're right, wasn't familiar with the recude method and now i understand that.

So for your example, how i'll now when all async actions has done? i don't see a place you invoke the general "callback"..

Comment: Could you explain this? For instance, in the `EachSeries` function, you call `Promise.resolve());` without specifying `Promise` anywhere. Also, what are the `p, item` that come from `array.reduce?`

Comment: @Startec - `.reduce()` accepts two arguments.  The first is a function, the second is the initial value of what you are reducing.  `Promise.resolve()` is producing that initial value.  The callback you pass is then called with two arguments.  The first argument is the current value in the reduction.  I've named that `p` in my code and it's initial value will be the `Promise.resolve()`.  Subsequent values will be the return value of my callback `return p.then(...)` which is another promise.  The second argument to the callback is the next value in the array that we are reducing.

Comment: @Startec - See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for doc on `.reduce()`.  You call it like this:  `var reducedValue = array.reduce(fn, initialValue)`.  My `Promise.resolve()` is that `initialValue`.  It's just a way to start a promise chain by initializing it to an already resolved promise.  It's kind of like `Promise.resolve().then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3)`.

Comment: I really appreciate your implementation.  Is this as simple as possible though?  I thought that promises were supposed to help create something like this more easily but this is much more complicated than just using the async library.

Comment: @Startec - When you factor in proper error handling and potential nested operations, promises are hands-down the best way to manage things.  Plus they are the core of `async` and `await` in ES7 so they are the future of the language too. If I wanted to sequence through an array asynchronously, I'd use something like `Promise.mapSeries()` in  the Bluebird promise library which is the library I generally use to add extended promise capabilities.

Comment: I see, but just looking at this code, I want to loop through an array of items, and sum the total by looking them up in a database, then send a response with the total.  This code here requires 5 `return` statements to do that.  It seems like a lot as I am still trying to wrap my head around all of them.

Comment: @Startec - Perhaps you should post a question with a good description of what you're trying to do and ask how the best way to do it with Promises is.  I can't see your actual problem in my head from just the words you're using so it would be better to see your code and then folks could offer better/different ways to do it.  I've never found a situation where using promises needed more code than not using promises.  Like with many things there are good ways to write promise code and not so good ways.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. The difference between the two approaches is that the first one creates a promise up front for each item in the list, whereas the second approach creates promises on demand. I'm trying to phase out the second approach, but I want to make sure I understand the real-world tradeoffs. Does the second approach scale better to longer lists than the first?

Comment: @DaveCausey - Yes, the first approach creates an initial promise chain of the entire length of the iteration in advance and then lets it run.  The other approaches chain one new promise at a time as the prior one resolves and the older ones can be GCed.  If you had a really long iteration (like millions), then the latter options might use a noticeably lower amount of peak memory.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to the [answer provided by @jib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040125/1641160)... you can also map an array of items to async functions like so:

```
[item1, item2]
    .map(item => async (prev_result) => await something_async(item))
    .reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve())
    .then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

Notice how `prev_result` will be the value returned by the previous evaluation of `something_async`, this is roughly equivalent to a hybrid between `async.eachSeries` and `async.waterfall`.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain by returning in the `then` callback. For instance:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
  resolve(1)
}).then(function(v){
  console.log(v);
  return v + 1;
}).then(function(v){
  console.log(v)
});
```

Will print:

> 1
>   
>  2

This of course work when asynchronously resolving promises:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(1);
  }, 1000)
}).then(function(result){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(result);
       resolve(result + 1);
     }, 1000)
   });
}).then(function(results){
  console.log(results);
});
```

Printing:

> 1
>   
> 2

Comment: Thanks, but i need it for a dynamic collection of data, not for some static known amount of iterations..

Comment: @ShlomiSasson It's just an example. All `then` does is return a promise, you pass callbacks and create promises as needed.

Comment: Kit, so what you say is to create a recursive function that attach more and more callbacks to the "then" method?

Comment: @ShlomiSasson Well you'd don't have to recurse, just what jfriend00 has done with reduce. There's a ES7 proposal to make this particular case easier btw: https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait

Answer (score 0):

//Uploading this for systems that run lower nodejs version (Azure :/)
Not the shortest but the nicest i can think of

for example lets say "functionWithPromise" returns some promise and expects some item.

```
functionWithPromise(item);

promisesArray =[];

//syncornized
itemsArray.forEach(function (item){
   promisesArray.push(functionWithPromise(item));
});

Promise.all(promisesArray).then(function (values){
//profit
});
```

Comment: This runs the promises in parallel, not in sequence