# Questions from the synchronous node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, web, commit

I would like synchronous results.
All I want'll want to enter data by dividing 5000 by one.
However, as a result of asynchronous listed it is struggling.
I want to see as a result of synchronous languages such as java.

I want these results:

```
100-elements
commit
100-elements
commit
100-elements
commit
100-elements
commit
```

However, the code currently gets these results:

```
100-elements
100-elements
100-elements
100-elements
100-elements
.
.
.
.
100-elements
commit
commit
commit
commit
commit
commit
commit
.
.
.
.
commit
```

How can I get these results? Please help me. Thank you.

```
mysql.getConnection(function(err, connection){

  if(err){ connection.release(); return; }

  var array = [];
  var count = 300000;
  var length = count;

  for(var i=0; i<count; i++){

    (function(currentI, master){
      process.nextTick(function(){

        array.push([currentI, master]);

        if(currentI % 5000 === 0){
          console.log('100-elements');
          array = [];

          connection.beginTransaction(function(err){
            if(err){
              throw err;
            }

            var query = "insert into users(username, password) values ?";

            connection.query(query, [array], function (err, rows) {

              if (!err) {
                //commit start
                connection.commit(function(){
                  if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    connection.rollback(function () {
                      console.error('rollback error');
                      throw err;
                    });
                  } else {
                    console.log("Commit");
                  }/ / if err
                    }); //commit end
                } else {
                                  console.log(err);
                connection.rollback(function(){
                  throw err;
                });
              } // if
            }) // cnnection query
          }); // beginTransaction
        } //if

      });
    }(i, 'master'));
  } //for
}) // getConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few design patterns you can use in node.js to run sequential asynchronous operations.  In all of them, you cannot run a tight loop waiting for something to happen - you have to let the single Javascript thread in node.js run and give it as many cycles as possible.

**Manual Iteration**

Put the code for an iteration in a local function (I usually call it `next()`) and then when one iteration calls its last completion function, you can call `next()` again to start the next iteration.  You can finish the operation either by testing some condition and not calling `next()` if things are done or the first lines of `next()` can test to see if you're done.

See the code example below for how your code would look like with manual iteration.

**Sequence promises**

If you use promises for your asynchronous operations, then you can let chained promises do all your sequencing for you as in `p().then(f1).then(f2).then(f3)`.  You can see an example of that in this answer: [Promises like async.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028552/es6-promises-something-like-async-each/32028826#32028826).

**Use the Async Module**

The [Async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) supports a number of async management functions.   Many find it very useful - others would prefer to use promises to solve similar problems.  In any case, it has a number of different functions for sequencing.  For example if you wanted to iterate an array asynchronously, you would use something like this:

```
async.eachSeries(hugeArray, function iterator(item, callback) {
  if (inCache(item)) {
    callback(null, cache[item]); // if many items are cached, you'll overflow
  } else {
    doSomeIO(item, callback);
  }
}, function done() {
  //...
});
```

---

Here's a version of your code that does the manual iteration using a custom `next()` iteration function.

```
function runQuery(callback) {
    mysql.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        var array = [];
        var count = 10;
        var index = 0;

        function next() {
            if (index++ < count) {
                array.push([index, 'master']);
                console.log('100-elements');
                connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        // can't throw here in an async function
                        // use callback to communicate error
                        callback(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    var query = "insert into users(username, password) values ?";
                    connection.query(query, [array], function(err, rows) {

                        if (!err) {
                            //commit start
                            connection.commit(function() {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                    connection.rollback(function() {
                                        console.error('rollback error');
                                        callback(err);
                                        return;
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Commit");
                                    // now do the next iteration
                                    next();
                                } // if err
                            }); //commit end
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                            connection.rollback(function() {
                                callback(err);
                                return;
                            });
                        } // if                    
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @deathquin - did this answer your question?

Comment: I don't have question Thank you !

Comment: @deathquin - then the procedure here on StackOverflow is that if you get a good answer, you can accept that answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the best answer.  That will earn some reputation points for both the person providing the answer (as their reward for helping you) and for you (for following a good procedure here).  Later on (when you've earned more reputation points), you can upvote all answers that helped you.