# Serial execution of functions returning promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

With ES2016 we now have promises and that's great. Unfortunately the functionality is very minimalistic and there is nothing like the series or waterfall as available in the async package.
If there a package providing this functionality for promises or how do people typically deal with those use cases?

Comment: Are you asking for a promise library?

Comment: That's what `.then` is for

Comment: @evolutionxbox if that's the way to go: yes

Comment: http://bluebirdjs.com/ ?

Comment: @trincot I understood bluebird.js more as a complete alternative to native promises. Can it also be used on top of native promises or are there alternatives that just enhance the native promises?

Comment: @paul so you would implement a waterfall execution of an array of function returning promises manually using .then()?

Comment: @materialdreams you can use `.reduce` to serially execute an array of  functions returning promises

Comment: Promises that adhere to the Promises/A+ specs can inter-operate, so using bluebird together with ES6 Promise objects will work.

Comment: Bluebird `mapSeries`. It can successfully coexist with native promises, though you may want to stick to Bb whenever possible because it offers good performance and a lot of good things. Depending on the situation, it may be a good idea to replace global `Promise` with Bb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Promises - something like async.each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028552/es6-promises-something-like-async-each)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To serially execute an array of functions returning promises you can use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
let final = functions.reduce((prev, f) => prev.then(f), Promise.resolve());
```

The "initial" argument `Promise.resolve()` is there to seed the chain of promises, since otherwise (if passed an array containing only a single function) the `.reduce` callback never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Most of this functionality already exists (or will exist) in the language:

- Run a bunch of actions simultaneously and get a Promise for an array of results: `Promise.all()`
- Run a bunch of actions and get the Promise for the first that resolves/rejects: `Promise.race()`
- Run a bunch of Promises serially: Use `reduce()` like the other answer mentions, or use the async iteration protocol.