# Making an async forEach()'

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently working on a script that will check all the the links of a page and highlight any broken links. Synchronously, this wasn't a major task, but I only just started working with Asynch, so any help with my code would be much appreciated.

```
var size = 0;
var itemsProcessed = 0;
    console.log("Size: " + size);

function linkCheck() {
var body = document.querySelectorAll("*");
var checker = Array.from($(body).filter("a"));
size = (Object.keys(checker).length);

    console.log("Size: " + size);
var list;

checker.forEach(function (anchor) {
    var link = $(anchor).attr("href");
    itemsProcessed++;
    console.log("Items: " + itemsProcessed);
    if (itemsProcessed == size) {
        colorUp(list);
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('HEAD', $(checker).attr("href"), true);
    itemsProcessed++;
    try {
        req.send(null);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        return true;
    }
    console.log(req.status);
    var data = (req.status !== 200);
    if (data) {
        //console.log("Added to List")
            list += data;
    }
    console.log(link, data);
});
}

function colorUp(list) {
console.log("DONE");
$(list).css({
    "border": "3px solid #ffb700",
    "background": "repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFE0B2, #FFE0B2 5px, #ffffff 5px, #ffffff 10px)"
});
}


linkCheck();
```

Currently, I'm having trouble waiting for the forEach to finish, but if you have any suggestions, or anything I can do to make the problem clearer, feel free to leave a post!

Thank you guys

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('a');' or `$('a')` to get all the anchors. Also decide if you're going to use jQuery or not. If you are, use it for everything and you'll be a lot happier. Note also that ajax (`XMLHttpRequuest`) is asynchronous, so `req.status` will not necessarily be correct when you are checking it.

Comment: Just because I'm unfamiliar with this, How can I make it wait till req.status is loaded before I check it? Also, how would I make the forEach portion asynchronous before I call colorUp()?

Thank you for responding Mike.

Comment: You'll want to do some research into Promises and a function named `Promise.all`. If you use jQuery's `$.ajax` method, it's a bit easier. Otherwise, you'll have to make `XMLHttpRequest` work with promises, which is no small undertaking. You could probably find a library that does it for you though. Basically, research, research, research :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Promises - something like async.each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028552/es6-promises-something-like-async-each)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for a number of requests to run one after another and do something after they finish you should use a `reduce` Array method.

```
checker.reduce((promise, anchor) => {
    return promise.then(() => $.ajax({type: "HEAD", url: $(anchor).attr("href")}));
}, $.Deferred().resolve()).then(responseFromLastRequest => {
    // Do your stuff here     
});
```

Or, if you don't care about the order of requests, you can run them simultaneously:

```
$.when.apply($, checker.map(anchor => {
    return $.ajax({type: "HEAD", url: $(anchor).attr("href")});
})).then(() => {
    // Do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As was said, working with XMLHttpRequest is not fun. Here is a complete example taking advantage of jQuery. While doing research about Promises is certainly a good idea, seeing it at work first might be better for a beginner.

```
function linkCheck() {
    var itemsProcessed = 0;

    var $checker = $('a');
    var size = $checker.length;
    console.log("Size: " + size);

    var $list = $();

    $checker.each(function (anchor) {
        var link = $(anchor).attr("href");
        itemsProcessed++;
        $.ajax(link, {
            type: 'HEAD',
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                var data = (req.status !== 200);
                if (data) {
                    $list.pushStack([anchor]);
                }
                console.log(link, data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                console.log("ERROR");
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log(req.status);
                console.log("Items: " + itemsProcessed);
                if (itemsProcessed == size) {
                    colorUp();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function colorUp() {

    console.log("DONE");
    $(list).css({
        "border": "3px solid #ffb700",
        "background": "repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFE0B2, #FFE0B2 5px, #ffffff 5px, #ffffff 10px)"
    });
}


linkCheck();
```

The `$.ajax(url, settings)` function takes as the second parameter an object that steers the 'waiting for a response' process. It defines a bunch of functions that are to be executed asynchronously at a later point in time, after the `linkCheck()` function has finished.

After a response from the server arrives, either the function listed for the `success` or the one listed for the `error` property is executed, and in both cases, after that the `complete` function gets executed.

The main point to remember is: if you define any sort of `send` function, the original function proceeds to execute without waiting for the answer. If you want to do something when the response arives, you have to define it in a closure.