# Execute an Array of promises sequentially without using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Lets say I have an array of promises. Each element of my array is a knex.js query builder and is ready to be executed and returns a promise.

How can I run each element of this array sequentially.
The array is built dynamically.

```
let promisesArray = [q1,q2,q3] ;
```

Each q is not a promise by itself but it will return a promise upon execution.

Comment: `promise.all()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: sequentially @FedeSc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Promises - something like async.each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028552/es6-promises-something-like-async-each)

Comment: if `q1, q2, q3` are promises, then it's too late to run them sequentially

Comment: Is it important that they *run* in order or do you just need the results in order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here could be a possible option:

```
let p = Promise.resolve([]);
promisesArray.forEach(q => {
  p = p.then(responses => {
    //based on the nature of each q, to start execution
    //use either q().then() or q.then()
    return q().then(response => {
      //Any further logic can be here.
      console.log(response);
      return responses.concat([response]);
    })
  })
})

p.then(responses => {
  // here you have all of the responses.
})
```

Comment: using reduce, this is a single line `promisesArray.reduce((p, q) => p.then(responses => q.then(response => [...responses, response])), Promise.resolve([]))`

Comment: not really, @Nnanyielugo - depends on what you know I guess

Comment: One-liners are usually not difficult to read to their authors :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.reduce to reduce the Array into one promise that chains them one after another

```js
let promisesArray = [q1,q2,q3] ;

function runSequentially(promiseArr) {
  return promiseArr.reduce((accum, p) => accum.then(p), Promise.resolve())
}

//Example, this prints.. 1, 2, 3 then "done".
runSequentially([Promise.resolve(1).then(console.log), Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log), Promise.resolve(3).then(console.log)]).then(() => console.log("done"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of bluebird promise, which should solve your issue. Keeping the concurrency value to 1, should execute promises sequentially.

```
    var Promise = require("bluebird");
    Promise.map([q1,q2,q3], {concurrency: 1})
```

Comment: I am really curious to know, why a negative vote is given for it. Do you think that it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your claim that q1, q2, q3 are "knex.js query builder and is ready to be executed and returns a promise",  get a function to execute itself with the next index when the promise is resolved. Call it with 0 first.

```
function awaitPromise(arr, idx) {

   arr[idx]().then(function(res) {

       console.log(res);

       if (idx < arr.length - 1)      
           awaitPromise(arr, idx + 1);
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/), you can use [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with concurrency set to `1`.

```
await Promise.map(arrayOfObj, async (obj) => {
    await this.someOperation();
  },
  {concurrency: 1}
);
```